# how to make lists of top five minimum values

Tags: r, output

say I have a spreadsheet that I imported or am working with a regular dataset. how do I retrieve a list of the top minimum values?

for example.

```
x<-c(6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13,14)
```

how do I get the position of the top 5 minimum values in the x vector (6,7,8,9,10)?

Comment: This is what the 'head' function is for.

Comment: What does "top minimum value" mean?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order` or `sort.list` to obtain the permutation of indices that can sort the object in ascending order (or descending if you pass `descending = TRUE`). Then you can obtain the necessary values using `head` or passing the indices (`[1:5]` in this example for the first five) directly

```
order(x)[1:5]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
sort.list(x)[1:5]
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sort` with `index.return = TRUE`

```
head(sort(x, index.return = TRUE)$ix,5)
```

---

Or with `order`

```
head(order(x),5)
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Why not just head(x , 5)?

Comment: I guess that could be. The example is not at all helpful. Either interpretation of the request is supported and the natural language request likewise is ambiguous.